# WCF net.tcp IIS Logging

Tags: wcf, iis, logging, net.tcp

Lately,all our services were switched from `basicHttpBinding` to `net.tcp`. Our services hosted in IIS. The problem is that with this change we lost our IIS logging abilities.

We aware about `WCF Tracing`,but our system utilities works, meanwhile, with `IIS` Logging only.

Is there some way to enable IIS logging of WCF net.tcp services?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It will not strait forward as with basic http binding, but it seems to be "done-able" - take a look on this posts:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/james_osbornes_blog/archive/2010/12/07/hosting-in-iis-using-nettcpbinding.aspx

or

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6db46819-e511-4ec2-9c3f-b09deaaedf79/logging-nettcpbinding-requests-in-the-iis-log

Comment: Sorry, but nothing new for us.As i said, WCF Tracer is currently not a solution. Thank you anyway

Comment: The first link is broken. It would be a great idea to summarize the link content in the post in addition to fixing the link. I think either of these links could replace it. https://jasper-net.blogspot.com/2010/12/hosting-in-iis-using-nettcpbinding.html or http://web.archive.org/web/20151231172034/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/james_osbornes_blog/archive/2010/12/07/hosting-in-iis-using-nettcpbinding.aspx